# JSON file load issue

Tags: iphone, json, file, load, titanium

I'm currently with this issue, it would be great if someone could give me some pointers or best practice. Titanium SDK version: 1.6.1 iPhone SDK version: 4.2

My app does the following, it is getting a remote JSON file for syncing my SQLite database, but the app is having this error while parsing the file

```
[INFO] Due to memory conditions, 0 of 0 images were unloaded from cache.
```

Everything works fine when working with smaller JSON files, but now the file reaches 7MB and the my code quits on me.

Is this because of a titanium JSON parse limitation? I can not provide the database with app installation, because of dynamic content. So this is already an excluded solution.

code:

```
function syncDatabase() {
    if ((Titanium.Network.networkType != Titanium.Network.NETWORK_NONE)) {
        Ti.API.info("There is network connection, trying to update database..");
        var conn = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient(); 
        conn.setTimeout(20000);
        var lastUpdated = Ti.App.Properties.getInt("lastUpdated");
        conn.open('GET', 'http://example.com/get/all/' + lastUpdated);
        filename = "db";
        conn.onload = function(){
            try {
                if (conn.status == 200)
                  {
                    var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,filename);
                    f.write(this.responseData);     
                  }
                  fillDatabase();
                }
            catch(e) {
            }
        }; 
        conn.send();
    }
}

function fillDatabase()
{
    try {
        var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory + "/db");
        var json = JSON.parse(file.read().text);   
        var db = Titanium.Database.open('db');
        for( i=0; i < json.length; i++){
            Ti.API.info("Found foobar: With id ["+json[i].id+"] ["+json[i].foo+"]");
            var syncid = json[i].id;
            var foo = json[i].foo;
            var bar = json[i].bar;
            db.execute('REPLACE INTO objects (id,foo,bar) VALUES (?,?,?)',syncid,foo,bar);
    }
    Ti.App.Properties.setInt('lastUpdated', Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000));
    db.close();
    }
    catch(e) {
        Ti.API.info("THERE IS AN ERROR UPDATING THE DATABASE");
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i have no idea actually but what do you mean with

> dynamic content

?
usually it should work with you're database as well

Comment: Hi! Sorry it took a while for me to reply I was on a 2 week holiday. With 'dynamic content' I meant the content in the database is changed often, so the database will have to be downloaded or synchronized to have the latest correct data. So that is why I mentioned I can not pack the database with installation.

In further development I saw I could reduce my JSON file to 1,5MB instead of 7MB and my application can sync my database at the moment because of that, but still I would like to see this issue fixed in case I have to expand my JSON file.